# How to convert the hex string to chunks of hex value in list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the below hex string i.e.,

```
hex_val = 010000263032efbfbdefbfbd42efbfbd
```

I need the result as,

```
[0x01,0x00,0x00,0x26,0x30,0x32,0xef,0xbf,0xbd,0xef,0xbf,0xbd,0x42,0xef,0xbf,0xbd]
```

I have tried with,

```
hex_string = "0x"+hex_val
value = hex_string[2:] if len(hex_string) % 2 == 0 else "0" + 
hex_string[2:]
print([",".join(value[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(value), 2))])
```

Comment: `re.sub("(.{2})",'0x\\1\n',hex_val).split()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[hex(int(hex_val[i]+hex_val[i+1], 16)) for i in range(0, len(hex_val), 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just turn them into a list. Try:

```py
hex_val = "010000263032efbfbdefbfbd42efbfbd"
hex_lst = ['0x'+hex_val[x:x+2] for x in range(0, len(hex_val), 2)]
print(hex_lst)
```

It will give you that values that you wanted. Though as strings.

```py
['0x01', '0x00', '0x00', '0x26', '0x30', '0x32', '0xef', '0xbf', '0xbd', '0xef', '0xbf', '0xbd', '0x42', '0xef', '0xbf', '0xbd']
```